# Select Case when Grouping(Column1) not working in Snowflake

Tags: sql, case, grouping, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to do the following query in Snowflake:

```
Select case when grouping(column_1) = 'Total'
        else column_1 end as column_1
       ,sum(column_2)
From Table
group by rollup(column_1)
```

But I keep getting the error: "SQL compilation error: GROUPING function cannot appear outside of SELECT, HAVING, and ORDER BY clauses."

Any suggestions on how to fix this or work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the query like this:

```
select (case when grouping(t.column_1) = 1
             then 'Total' else column_1
        end) as column_1,
      sum(column_2)
From Table t
group by rollup(t.column_1);
```

That is, qualify the reference in the `GROUP BY` so it is not resolved to the column alias.  Also, note that this fixes the `case` expression.